# Не вызывается onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, activity

Для получения разрешения android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW на Android Marshmallow (6.0) использую вот такой код:

```
public class GeneralActivity extends Activity {

public final static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = -1010101;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Context Context = getBaseContext();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(Context)) {

            View APIM = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.apim, null);
            setContentView(APIM);

            Button ALLOW_BUTTON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.allow_button_apim);

            View.OnClickListener ALLOW_BUTTON_ACTION = new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            };

            ALLOW_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(ALLOW_BUTTON_ACTION);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {

    Log.d("CALLED", "OnActivity Result"); 
}
}
```

По нажатию кнопки действительно открывается диалог, в котором я даю приложения права и нажимаю кнопку "назад" и это возвращает меня обратно к приложению, но в onActivityResult ничего не поступило.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по гуглу именно с этим разрешением всё плохо. Куча багов и нормального решения нема на данный момент. Можно лишь попробовать вешать флаг в активити перед запуском настроек, что они запрашиваются сейчас и при следующем вызове `onResume()` проверить ещё раз разрешение. Если оно есть - значит всё ок - иначе юзер отменил/не включил.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Permission не вернется в onActivityResult, а вернется в onRequestPermissionsResult. переопределите его и все